# Container Background Not Repeating

Tags: height, containers, repeat, css

Alright, I have designed a website, with a transparent background/repeatable image. What I want to do is have it repeat all the way to the bottom of the page...

I want tried applying height to the container background including an also min-height of 100% to both elements, and seeing as the container and content within the container do not have a parent element besides "body" and or "html", I do not know how else I am supposed to keep this background repeating until it is literally connected to the bottom of the window.

It seems that I keep having recurring issues with making a background image repeat itself. 'Tis very aggravating.

I implore someone to please help me figure out this recurring issue. Hopefully my question may be solved and also answers. Thank you StackOverflow community.

Thank you very much!
Aaron :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your container css try this:

```
background:url(images/containerback-01.png) repeat-y;
```

Without seeing your code it is a little hard to help.

Comment: Just so you know, the default behavior of the background property is to repeat. So there is no need to declare repeat-y here unless you do not want the image to repeat horizontally. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-repeat)

Answer (score 1):

An example would help, but if you are experiencing an issue where your background is ending where your content ends (leaving a big white gap afterwards), this should help:

```
html {
height:100%;
background: blue;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

The background should now stretch the entire length of the page. A [codepen](http://codepen.io/) of your problem could help generate more specific answers.